# csv file column reading and extracting using python

Tags: python, csv

i have the following code...

```
reader=csv.DictReader(open("test1.csv","r"))
allrows = list(reader)

keepcols = [c for c in allrows[0] if all(r[c] != '0' for r in allrows)]

print keepcols
writer=csv.DictWriter(open("output1.csv","w"),fieldnames='keepcols',extrasaction='ignore')
writer.writerows(allrows)
```

i have a csv file which has about 45 cols..
the first column has some names..
except the first column, all others have only 0's and 1's...
and of course, the whole table has some titles as well..
i m trying to read columns from csv file and i need to extract only those cols with 1's
the problem is the output file is empty even though there are a few columns in the table with 1's..

could somebody please help me out.... :( i m stuck terribly..

```
Title    3003_contact    3003_backbone   3003_sidechain  3003_polar  3003_hydrophobic    3003_acceptor   3003_donor  3003_aromatic
l1  1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
l1  1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
l1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
l1  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
l1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
l2  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
l2  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
l3  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
l3  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
l3  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
l3  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
l3  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
l4  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
l4  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
l4  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

it returns only column 1... I've tried changing 'keepcols' to keepcols... and I get column2 first and then column1 as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** If the input file is a comma-separated values file, then 
to maintain the order of the keys, use `reader.fieldnames` instead of the keys in `allrows[0]`.

So the solution would be:

```
keepcols = [c for c in reader.fieldnames if any(r[c] != '0' for r in allrows)]
```

The input file posted above looks like it has space-separated columns. In this case, I don't think `csv` is the right tool for parsing it. Instead, you can use `split`:

```
import csv
with open("test1.csv","r") as f:
    fields=next(f).split()
    # print(fields)
    allrows=[]
    for line in f:
        line=line.split()
        row=dict(zip(fields,line))
        allrows.append(row)
        # print(row)
    keepcols = [c for c in fields if any(row[c] != '0' for row in allrows)]
    print keepcols
    writer=csv.DictWriter(open("output1.csv","w"),fieldnames=keepcols,extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writerows(allrows)
```

**Edit2:** The reason why the column order was changing is because `for c in allrows[0]` returns the keys of `allrows[0]` in an unspecified order. `dict` keys are not ordered by default. The above code works around this by defining `fields` to be a list, not a `dict`.

**Original answer:**
Change `fieldnames='keepcols'` to `fieldnames=keepcols`.

`fieldnames` needs to be a sequence of keys, such as `['fieldA','fieldB',...]`.

A potential pitfall to be aware of in Python is that strings are sequences. When you iterate over a string, you get the characters of the string. So when you say `fieldnames='keepcols'`, you are setting `fieldnames` to be the sequence of characters `['k','e','e','p','c','o','l','s']`. You don't get an error because this is a valid sequence of keys. But your list of dicts, `allrows` doesn't happen to have these keys. `writer.writerows` blithely ignores this since `extrasaction='ignore'`.

Comment: tried changing... i get column2 first and then column1 only as ouput... the remaning cols do not appear... but i need to extract a column even if it has a single 1... please help....

Comment: so wat should i do about it..??i m really lost... :(

Comment: Change the `all` to `any`. By the way, that you wanted this wasn't very clear from the original question.

Comment: ok i m so sorry... i ll ask my questions more clearly hereafter... i changed 'all' to 'any' and it worked... but in my output... the order of the csv table seems to change.. the title column is not in its place... it appears as the 4th column... pl help...

Comment: i want only those cols which have atleast one non zero element... and this is definitely a csv file whose separator is comma.... but your code is also helpful for another problem that i currently have.. thank you so much :)

Comment: thanks ubuntu.... u rock.... it still worked... i just changed the split function to split (',')

Comment: just a small hitch... wat if i want to get the title row as well??? as in the name of the particular column with the header as wel...  
as in the column names.... ??

Comment: Use `writer.writeheader()` to write the header. See http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader

Comment: um, wat if i m using python 2.6? it seems this attribute does not exist in python 2.6... should i upgrade right away or is there a better way to do it ??

Comment: Well, I wouldn't upgrade just for this. This should work: `writer.writerow(dict(zip(keepcols,keepcols)))`