# Extract a column from a .csv file by name

Tags: python, csv

I have an .csv file like this:

```
  Name                    |    Twitter handle
  3 Degrees Incorporation |    3Degrees_Inc
```

the first row is the column names and the second row is the contents to each of the two columns.

If I want to extract data listed under the column "Twitter handle", what would be the right python code to use?

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222831/csv-file-column-reading-and-extracting-using-python?rq=1

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't really a valid CSV format (or, rather, if you interpret it as a CSV according to [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180.html) or any reasonable dialect thereof, most of your values have extra whitespace before and after them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open(csvfile) as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True):
        do_something_with(row['Twitter handle']
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) for more information… but there's not that much more to it than this.

But really, this isn't a proper CSV, and you're just getting lucky that you're asking for the last column, because all the other columns have terminal whitespace as well as initial whitespace, and there's no way to skip that. So, if you wanted to handle any other column, you'd need something like this:

```
with open(csvfile) as f:
    headers = next(csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True))
    headers = [header.strip() for header in headers]
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=headers, 
                              delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True):
        do_something_with(row[colname].strip())
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. It's just that I am keep getting syntax error at the command ` headers = [header.strip() for header in headers]`...python doesn't seem to recognize the `headers`.....how can I solve it?

Comment: That almost always means you're missing a close parens/bracket/quote/etc. on the previous line. I can't debug it any better than that without your actual code and traceback.