# using shell cut csv file

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I want to cut CSV file by column names.

Sample file:

```
"column A","column B","column C","column D","column E",
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,
111,222,333,444,555
```

column_A:

```
$ cat column_A
aaa
111
```

column_B:

```
$ cat column_B
bbb
222
```

when I using `awk` but it's not success. Some time when we meet `\n` in `""`.

Like this:

```
aaa,ssss,"zzz 
xxx"
```

but this should be a line what should I do?
just 1 " it can be successful
but when csv file have too may \n and too may “ on line 
it's
can't be success

```
function isallline(){
    LineNumber=$1
    LineInfo=`echo "$2"|tr -d '\n'`
    FileName=$3
    LastLineNumber=$4
    GetInfo=`echo "$LineInfo"|awk -F '"' '{print NF-1}'`
    IsAl=$((GetInfo%2))

    if [[ $IsAl != 0 ]]
    then
        LineNumber=$((LineNumber+1))

        LineInfo="$LineInfo""`sed -n ''$LineNumber'p' $FileName|tr -d '\n'`"      

       if [[ $LineNumber -le $LastLineNumber ]]
        then
            isallline $LineNumber "$LineInfo" $FileName $LastLineNumber
        else
            echo "error with not complte'\"'"
        fi

    else
        echo "$LineInfo" >>CSVFile
        return $LineNumber
    fi
}

function GetCsvFile()
{ 
    FileName=$1
    >CSVFile                                                              #-- clearn file --
    i=1                                                                   #-- declare i=1 --
    LasetLineNumber=`wc -l $FileName|awk '{print $1 }'`
    LineNumber=0                                                          #-- declare LineNumber=0 --
    while read LINE                                                       #-- read file --
    do
        getinfo=`echo $LINE|awk -F '"' '{print NF-1}'`                    #-- get count(") --
        if [[ $getinfo != 0 ]] 
        then
           if [[ $LineNumber == 0 ]]
            then 
                isallline $i "$LINE" $FileName LasetLineNumber            #-- call function isallline --
                LineNumber=$?                                             #-- get function isallline return(LineNumber) --
            elif [[ $LineNumber -lt $i ]]
            then
                isallline $i "$LINE" $FileName LasetLineNumber
                LineNumber=$?
            fi
        fi 
        if [[ $i -gt $LineNumber ]]
        then
            echo $LINE >> CSVFile                          
        fi  
    let i++
    done < $FileName
}
```

Comment: someone have another solution? about CSV file? just using shell

Comment: Hold on — you expected an answer in 3 minutes?  That's … a trifle optimistic.  You may get lucky, but...

Comment: If you've got to deal with the full generality of CSV format, with commas within double quotes, and newlines within quoted strings, then you need a tool designed to handle that level of complexity — and not a general purpose tool being used to handle it. You can deal with well-formed data that doesn't spread over multiple lines but it's hard; once you've got multiple lines in a field, it's time to get the specialized tools. Depending on your knowledge, Python has a CSV module, Perl has several CSV modules, and there's csvfix (probably on GitHub now; was on Google Code). And there'll be others.

Comment: thanks i have a idea but some time it's can't work. and this solution not good

Comment: You are using the wrong tools for the job.  You probably can do it all in `awk`, but it is time to move to tools designed to handle the complexity of the data you are dealing with.

Comment: Here's a Python solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507425/extract-a-column-from-a-csv-file-by-name

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it's possible to write such regexp, which will be able to parse CSV. But [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/215171) is brilliant answer why it's more or less practically impossible. You better use specific parser. Actually, almost any linux system has python installed and python [includes tooling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse CSV files